# special character in ISO-8859-1

Tags: c#, iso-8859-1

I'm reading HTML pages with C#. Requesting for page like firefox. The site `charset=ISO-8859-1` (which I'm using). But I cannot manage to get `‰`. I get `?` mark in its place when I'm requesting for source code. Other special character like `é` are fine. Any suggestions why? And what should I do?

Comment: That's the per-mille sign, and is &#137; in iso-8859-1. Are you sure that site's sending out 8859 and not something else under an 8859 guise?

Comment: That's U+2030, a glyph that's not supported by iso-8859-1.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1#Codepage_layout

Comment: @MarcB It isn't in iso-8859-1, but it is in MS extension to  iso-8859-1: [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout). In ISO-8859-1 codes 127–159 (inclusive) are not defined.

Comment: @Richard thnx, u saved my day. needed to use that extension ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted elsewhere in the responses *there is no per-mille* sign in ISO 8859-1.

However you can send is as an entity (`&#8240`). As the underlying model of HTML (like XML) is Unicode, characters that cannot be represented in the text encoding, but are in Unicode, can be included as entities.

Answer (score 1):

The `‰` character is not part of the ISO-8859-1 encoding and it cannot be represented with it.

This can be easily demonstrated with the following snippet:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var input = "‰";
        var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        var buffer = encoding.GetBytes(input);
        input = encoding.GetString(buffer);
        // prints a ? because ISO-8859-1 cannot represent this character
        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }
}
```

So I guess you have to use some other encoding such as UTF-8 which allows to represent this character.

Comment: but then i don't get special characters like `é` and others

Comment: @Buar: You need to make sure *everything* agrees on the encoding. You haven't provided any code for either the server side or the client side, which makes it very hard to show what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The character `'‰'` is **not** in ISO-8859-1. However, it **is** in [codepage 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which is often confused with ISO-8859-1.

The best solution is to use `&#8240;` as Richard suggests, *and/or* to change from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8.

(There's also the possibilty to switch to codepage 1252 (`Windows-1252`), but there's a risk it won't work for all users. That would be `charset="windows‑1252"`.)

Comment: Thnx Richard already told me that in comments. I already solved my problem ^^

Answer (score -1):

```
public static string stringToISO8859str(string textToConvert)
        {
            Encoding iso8859 = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
            byte[] srcTextBytes = iso8859.GetBytes(textToConvert);
            byte[] destTextBytes = Encoding.Convert(iso8859, unicode, srcTextBytes);
            char[] destChars = new char[unicode.GetCharCount(destTextBytes, 0, destTextBytes.Length)];
            unicode.GetChars(destTextBytes, 0, destTextBytes.Length, destChars, 0);
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(textToConvert.Length + (int)(textToConvert.Length * 0.1));
            foreach (char c in destChars)
            {
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(c);
                if (value == 34)
                    result.AppendFormat("&quot;");
                else if (value == 38)
                    result.AppendFormat("&amp;");
                else if (value == 39)
                    result.AppendFormat("&apos;");
                else if (value == 60)
                    result.AppendFormat("&lt;");
                else if (value == 62)
                    result.AppendFormat("&gt;");
                else
                    result.Append(c);
            }
            return result.ToString();            
        }
```